# List files with certain dates?

Tags: r

Assuming I have two directories with some files for one year(2010/01/01-2010/12/31). The files are named like this:
dirct1:

```
fs_df_20100101F00_20100101F88_777_0009.dat 
fs_df_20100102F00_20100102F88_777_0009.dat
etc.............(only the date change)
```

dirct2:

```
gf_gh_20100101F00_20100101F88_788_08.dat 
gf_gh_20100102F00_20100102F88_788_08.dat
etc.............(only the date change)
```

This will list all files in dir1 and dir2 for all dates. however some files (dates) are missing in dir1. But what I need is to list only files in dir2 that share the same date with dir1. (if the date is missing in dir1, do not list it in dir2).......

Comment: `intersect(dir1, dir2)` ?

Comment: Good point! @csgillespie In that case could also do: `lapply(intersect( substr(dir1, 7,14), (dir2, 7,14) ), do-something)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to extract the dates from the file names. Since you have consistent naming system, you can avoid regular expressions and use `substr`

```
dir1 = c("fs_df_20100101F00_20100101F88_777_0009.dat", "fs_df_20100102F00_20100102F88_777_0009.dat")
dir2 = c("gf_gh_20100101F00_20100101F88_788_08.dat", "gf_gh_20100102F00_20100102F88_788_08.dat")

substr(dir1, 7, 14)
#[1] "20100101" "20100102"
```

Then determine which dates in `dir1` are in `dir2` using `which` and the `%in%` operator

```
matching = which(substr(dir1, 7, 14) %in% substr(dir2, 7, 14))
```

Then just use

```
dir1[matching]
```